# Is it possible to use the scons CacheDir in a read-only way

Tags: scons

What is says really. We need a cache because most files are built using the same versions of every file, but any developer who is altering files will only be altering a few files, and generally they get altered a lot.

There's little point in writing that change into the cache specified with CacheDir() until it is approved for production, but there's a lot of point in copying stuff from CacheDir

But I can only see options to disable the cache entirely.

(I'd post this to the scons mailing lists but it's just come up with a completely illegible captcha)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 different options:

1. Instead of a CacheDir, how about using a Repository() for those files that almost never change?
2. Consider using the `--implicit-deps-unchanged` option as described in the SCons man pages, and [here](http://www.scons.org/wiki/GoFastButton).

[Here](http://scons.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1272&dsMessageId=515081)'s a similar discussion.

How do you plan on *toggling* the read-only behavior? You'll need some logic to do that. Since its not possible to use the CacheDir in a read-only way, an alternative would be to use this same toggling logic to switch between using a Repository and the CacheDir.

Comment: 1) as far as I understand it, implicit-deps-unchanged refers to checking dependencies used to build derived objects, not the actual derived objects
2) because storing objects in the repository would be messy. technically the objects change quite frequently, but any developer is likely to pick up the latest versions.

Comment: @TomTanner, I dont think its possible to use the CacheDir in a read-only manner. I updated my answer with another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Fwiw, scones has this now. Version 2.3.1

From: http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html

scons can maintain a cache of target (derived) files that can be shared between multiple builds. When caching is enabled in a SConscript file, any target files built by scons will be copied to the cache. If an up-to-date target file is found in the cache, it will be retrieved from the cache instead of being rebuilt locally. Caching behavior may be disabled and controlled in other ways by the --cache-force, --cache-disable, --cache-readonly, and --cache-show command-line options. The --random option is useful to prevent multiple builds from trying to update the cache simultaneously.

Comment: Um, yes, that's because I added it *blush*